# System.ServiceModel.ClientBase connected to Service

Tags: wcf

I have the following code:

```
public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<...

if (m_MyClient == null)
    m_MyClient = new MyServiceClient
        ("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService", remoteAddress);

WriteOutput("Successfully connected to service");
```

My question is how do i know that my client actually connected to the service at this point? I would like to display a message of either failure or success.

Answer (score 2):

When you've created the client, and no exception like `EndpointNotFoundException` has occured - then you are "connected" to the service which really means: the communication channel between the client and the service is ready to be used for sending messages back and forth. That's all there is - there's nothing on the server side yet to really handle your calls (except for the channel listener which will get activated if a message arrives).

You can also check the client channel's `.State` property - ideally, it should be `Opened` at that point:

Use this if you're deriving from `ClientBase<T>`

```
m_MyClient.State == CommunicationState.Opened
```

or this is you're using the standard client class generated by the `Add Service Reference` functionality in Visual Studio:

```
(m_MyClient as IClientChannel).State == CommunicationState.Opened
```

Comment: The following code of mine:

m_MyClient = new MyServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService", remoteAddress);

never raises an exception. Only when i try to communicate with the service, do i get an exception.

I would like to find out right after that code if my client actually connected?

Comment: @Tamer: **WHAT** exception do you get??? In WCF, you're not really "connected" per se - you have a channel available to send messages - but there's no real connection like with ADO.NET or anything like that...

Comment: Update:
The following code:
(m_MyClient as IClientChannel).State == CommunicationState.Opened
 crashes.

The correct thing is:
m_MyClient.State == CommunicationState.Opened

Now the interesting thing  is that the CommunicationState is always created. Its never actually opened, it always remains Created. It only becomes opened after a communication actually happens. Like after i make a call to:

m_MyClient.GetComments();

and then i check the state, only then is it opened.

Answer (score 1):

After realizing what i mentioned in my above comment, i realized the answer to my question was as follows:

In my ServiceContract i added the following:

```
[OperationContract]
bool IsAlive();
```

Whose implentation simply looks as follows:

```
public bool IsAlive()
{
    return true;
}
```

Then changed my code as follows:

```
m_MyClient = new MyServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService", remoteAddress);

try
{
    m_MyClient.IsAlive();
}
catch (EndpointNotFoundException)
{
    WriteOutput("Unable to connect to service");

    m_MyClient = null;
}

if (m_MyClient != null)
    WriteOutput("Successfully connected to service");
```

Comment: This is off-topic, but now i have to wait for about a minute before the exception is fired, since this all gonna be running on a local network, how do i decrease that timeout period? 
I tried decreasing the receiveTimeout on my client, but it didn't work.